# PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION in CMake

Tags: testing, cmake

I have been reading the [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/).

The section "Installing and Testing (Step 3)" has the following test script:

```
add_test (TutorialComp25 Tutorial 25)
set_tests_properties (TutorialComp25 
  PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "25 is 5")
```

According to the CMake documentation, `add_test` is straightforward, but I don't follow how [`set_tests_properties`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/set_tests_properties.html?highlight=set_tests_properties) works; especially this "25 is 5".

It sounds like

```
if (INPUT_ARG is OUTPUT_RESULT)
  test passed
else
  test failed
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_test/PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION.html):

> The output must match this regular expression for the test to pass.
>
> If set, the test output will be checked against the specified regular expressions and at least one of the regular expressions has to match, otherwise the test will fail.

The first test of the tutorial example (called `TutorialRuns`) doesn't have any properties set.  This means CTest will treat the test as having passed if the `Tutorial` exe returns `0` on completion, having been passed the argument `25`.

In the second test, the call

```
set_tests_properties (TutorialComp25 PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "25 is 5")
```

means that the console output from running the `Tutorial` exe with an arg of `25` must contain the string `"25 is 5"` to be considered a pass.  The return value is ignored in this case.  Since the test exe outputs:

```
The square root of 25 is 5
```

it passes.

Remember that it's a regex that's being applied.  If the `PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION` was set to e.g. `"^25 is 5"`, the test would fail, since this is looking for the phrase `25 is 5` at the **start** of the output.  There's a brief description of CMake's regex syntax in the documentation for the [`string`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/string.html) command.